# Can’t take network interface down on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, mac-address, network-interface

I'm trying to change my WiFi MAC address following this article:
https://www.linuxshelltips.com/change-mac-address-linux/

After taking down my network manager, when I try to take down the network interface using:

```
ifconfig wlp*** down
```

I get the following message:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I assume that running `sudo` like this would help: `sudo ifconfig wlp*** down`

Comment: I was just about to comment that I was able to change my MAC address using the syntax $ sudo macchanger -m [your_custom_MAC_address] [Targeted_network_interface]
without taking down the network interface (i.e., after only stopping the network manager), but using sudo as per your suggestion works to take down the interface. Thanks!

Comment: How strange...now when I try to change the MAC address again after stopping the network manager, I get the following error, both WITH and without taking down the interface: [ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Cannot assign requested address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that running `sudo` like this would help:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp*** down
```

Comment: Thanks, I would upvote but I can't yet; do you know how to bypass the second error I'm getting?